# Printing only selected features in report QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, reports

My layer has more than 2900 elements, and I would like to release a map with 1 or 10 or 50 selected elements but never 2900 in the time.

I can't select them other than visually (no column to identify).
Do you have an idea to output a report with only the selected elements?

I have tried the different solutions already seen on this site but nothing that allows me to release a report without saving many unnecessary layers.

Comment: save as virtual layer? https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers  then print that virtual layer

Comment: Or make a duplicate of your layer and include some filtering options

Answer (score 7):

If you are using QGIS 3.x, try the following steps:

1. Use the Field Calculator to create a new **virtual field** (integer type), called `selected`, and enter the expression `is_selected()`
2. Go to your Map Layout and under the Atlas settings > Filter with, enter the expression `"selected" = 1`
3. Now select your features on the main canvas
4. Go back to the Map Layout and enable the atlas (disable first if already enabled) to refresh the filter.

(Don't forget that your map element must be controlled by the atlas. Select the map element, go to Item Properties and tick 'Controlled by Atlas')

Just keep cycling between 3 and 4 every time you want to select a different set.
You don't have to call the virtual field `selected`; it can be anything you want. Just make sure you then refer to its name in step 2.

Note: I have tried directly entering `is_selected(@atlas_feature)` (and variants) in the Atlas Filter and it didn't seem to work (Q 3.6)

Note also that the Virtual Field does not auto update in an open Attribute Table - you need to open a new table to confirm the updated values.

This won't work in QGIS 2.x as `is_selected()` is not available.

Comment: is_selected() in Filter works in QGIS 3.16. No need for a virtual field anymore