# Show/hide individual selected feature QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

Is it possible to select individual features of a layer on a map and hide them? (I am working with 3.8.3-Zanzibar version of QGIS).

I need to print different maps of a close by area and I want to show only the symbols that are relevant in each case, but not others close by.

In the example below, I have selected the points (in yellow) that I would like to momentarily hide.

[image]

I know I could add a column in the associated table with a numeric field and fill in the ones I need to show with 1, the rest with 0 and then apply a filter. But I was looking for something more direct, like the show/hide label button.

Comment: Put them on a different layer, or classify the data and turn different classes on/off.

Comment: If there few of those maps have to be produce than try a `Filter`? Otherwise I will suggest to work around with an Atlas in Print Composer.

Comment: Thanks Erik and Taras, but my question was trying to avoid both suggestions: I didn't want to create more layers for only a print screen that takes a second. The Filter solution is how I am working at the moment: I select the items I want to show, update column of the selected ones, then filter, then print screen, and move on (which implies, unfilter, clear selection update column again, etc...). That's why I was just looking for a simple button.

Comment: Does this question help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322070/is-it-possible-to-see-the-selected-geometry-in-the-map-composer-and-change-the

Comment: Looks also similar to this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414379/showing-only-filtered-features-using-rule-based-symbology-in-qgis

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using Rule based symbology with a rule based on [`is_selected()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-selected) function and a symbol layer which is not enabled - see below for details.

*Selected features disappear visually, but appear again when deselected:*
[image]

Change layer rendering from `Single Symbol` to [`Rule-based`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-renderer) and define two styles:

- The first one with the rule `not is_selected()` that shows the points that are not selected. Style it as you like the points to appear.
- The second one with the rule `is_selected()`. Double click on the rule, select the marker icon and at the very bottom, uncheck the box `Enable symbol layer`: like this, all selected features will not be displayed any more.

[image]

Comment: Yep that is definitely cleaner +1

Answer (score 5):

It's not the cleanest but you can just set the symbology size to 0 if the feature is selected to "hide" it.

expression -> `if(is_selected(), 0, 4)`

[image]
[image]

Comment: I recommend you use open source ShareX for screen casting: https://getsharex.com (It does not insert the logo).

Comment: @ComradeChe Thanks it does look better

Comment: Thanks as well @ComradeChe - used the software for an animated gif as well, works nice and is intuitive to use.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of tasks, I used the *Auto filtre 3* plugin.

Description translated from the plugin's page :

*This plugin allows you to filter the active layer with the objects selected geographically automatically or by attribute and to log the filters to return to the previous one*

Unfortunately, this plugin is only available in French but there might be an English alternative but I'm not aware of it.
However, the use of the plugin is easy even if it's not translated.

[image]

There is two different types of filter available after selecting some entities you want to hide (or keep, depending on the situation), by id or by attribute.

By id, the plugin will automatically create a new filter on the layer (*reseau* in my example) to keep all the selected entities :

```
cast("id_res" as text) IN ('11233','11612')
```

By field, the plugin will create a new filter matching the values of the selected field (in *Champ 1*, *Champ 2* and *Champ 3*) of the selected entities :

```
type IN ('ROAD','RIVER')
```

You can combine up to three fields in the same filter.

This two method allows you to keep the selected entities but if you want to hide them, just change the filter by replacing *IN* by *NOT IN*.