# Showing only filtered features using Rule-based symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, filter, select-by-attribute, visualisation

I have a layer called *'A'* with a field called `"B"`, under this field, there are multiple values such as "C, D, E..." (one value for each row/feature in the attribute table). I have been trying to use `is_selected()` function in the rule, but I kept getting `0` results returned.

I am just trying to show the filtered features for a layer. E.g., only showing the features with "C" in Field `"B"` on the current layer, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question (why you are trying to use `is_selected`). If you are just trying to filter features in your layer, right click your layer in TOC, select 'Filter' and use expression e.g. `"B" LIKE 'C'`.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there were two features selected in the polygon layer *'test'*. Afterwards, the Rule-based symbology was applied using the [`is_selected()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#is-selected) function.

[image: main_1]

When I unpick the category without the `is_selected()` the following result will pop up (which will be also true in the Print Composer)

[image: main_2]

However, IMHO the `is_selected()` function shows its real "power" in the Print Composer.

[image: print_composer]