# Atlas automation for rule based symbols QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, atlas

I am working with a point and polygon data set in atlas and I have enabled rule based symbology. I have already explored and worked with the standard work flow of (is_selected) and else rules. Since this basic on or off command is very useful, I would like to know if there is a way that I can code into the atlasfeatureid a selection command to highlight the feature in the map canvas to satisfy the rule based selection.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Could you clarify what you mean by "highlight the feature in the map canvas"? Do you want the feature to look differently in the map canvas (i.e. the main QGIS window) if it is the current feature in your atlas, or are you looking for an expression for rule-based selection that selects the current feature in your atlas?

Comment: Thank you, happy to be here!! Highlight in this case is select a feature in the main canvas window, then of course it will appear in the atlas extent. I am looking for an expression that selects the feature in atlas, and my selection queries are rudimentary at best.

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if that helps? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314198/printing-only-selected-features-in-report-qgis-3